# Android: Switching to another activity using a button event?

Tags: android, android-button

I want to change the current activity to another activity in android using a button. However whenever I click the button, eclipse debug perspective comes up with the error "source not found". This is the function I'm using to change the activity

```
public void toManager(){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DegreeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In my xml file, the button has an onClick listener. This is the xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_toDegree"
    android:text="@string/btn_toDegree"
    android:textSize="13pt"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:onClick="toManager"  <!-- This line -->
    />
```

If I call the `toManager()` function in the `onCreate()` block of the first activity, It switches to the next activity with no error. However when I try to switch using the button it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click handler must look like:

```
public void toManager(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DegreeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

From [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) documentation:

> Now, when a user clicks the button, the Android system calls the
>   activity's `selfDestruct(View)` method. In order for this to work, the
>   method must be public and accept a `View` as its only parameter.

Comment: You can just ignore it but the signature of handler must be `public void methodName(View)`. That's because Android uses reflection to find handler and it can find your method because it has wrong signature.